# so how do you use foreach with @unless

Tags: laravel-5.4

i am trying to show all the message a user have in the message table but the bellow code give me an error someone please help?

@unless(is_null(Auth::user()->message))

```
{{ Auth::user()->message->name }}

@foreach(Auth::user()->message as $message)
    {{ $message->name }}
@endforeach
```

@else

```
<p>No messages</p>
```

@endunless

Answer (score 0):

Why use unless with an else? Why not just an @if 
Not even sure else works with @unless. At least I can't find any examples of this.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade

Does this work: ?

```
@if(!is_null(Auth::user()->message))

{{ Auth::user()->message->name }}

@foreach(Auth::user()->message as $message)
    {{ $message->name }}
@endforeach 
@else

<p>No messages</p>
@endif
```

Comment: If Auth::user()->message is an array, you cant call {{ Auth::user()->message->name }} ?

Comment: This is the Error message i always get from my server sir : Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

Comment: Then you have to go step by step and debug to find the cause of the error.
Try removing the whole thing and just try {{ Auth::user()->message }}

Comment: My previous code worked well without foreach statement but i only get one message

Comment: Well then the Auth::user()->message only returns one message, not an array of messages. My best guess.

Comment: it said : Trying to get property of non-object (View: /home/monezwxn/public_html/resources/views/home.blade.php)